# what changes are necessary to convert of ios 7 to ios 4 app

Tags: ios, iphone

I am asking this question only for concept. I have developed an app which deployment target is io7.0 but now I want to give support for ios4.o also what changes I should take care?

1. If I will change the deployment target does code crash?
2. If my deployment target is ios4 and device/simulator I have selected is iphone 5, what would happen?

Any reference will appreciate..

Comment: The current minimum is iOS 4.3. You can't support 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Setting anything below a deployment target of 6.0 is really asking for trouble these days.  If you set a deployment target less than 6.0, you cannot build for 64bit.

[Only 5% of devices in the wild are running OS versions less than iOS 7](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/11/11/ios8-56-percent-adoption/), and I'd imagine that the vast majority of that 5% are running iOS 6.1, so it's not really worth supporting anything below 6.0.  If you set a deployment target of 6.0 or 6.1, then your app will be able to run on iPhone 3GS and later.

As such, I suggest you use a deployment target of 6.1 if you really want to support legacy users.

If you select a device (simulator or real) in the run destinations, then your app will run on that device.  The deployment target affects how your app builds; it is the minimum OS version you intend to support.